# While setting the constraints in storyboard, Xcode crashes continuously

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, xcode-storyboard, xcode6.3

After adding constraints in many UI controls using storyboard, when I tried to edit existing constraint, Xcode crashes unexpectedly. This is happening while adding new constraints, too. This happens continuously to Xcode and having random behavior. Currently I am using Xcode Version 6.3.

Below is crash report:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the crash report?

Comment: Hi please put your crash report in question so that we can help you ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your concern.

After many tries, I am able to work with Xcode. I am not able find a root cause but take a different way to come out of it.

After crashing many times, I thought rather than putting many views in one view controller having extensive amount of constraints, take separate views and set constraints in it and add those views into host view controller at run time.